# Is it possible to remove a window that is lying on top of 3 other windows in a row?

Tags: interface, customization

Suppose you have 4 windows in 2 rows. The first row has one window and the bottom row has 3. Is it possible to remove the top window?

[image: illustration]

Comment: The workaround I was thinking of was removing the top editor with the info window, but of course that doesn't work..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find any particularly good and fast way around this, this is the best I could come up with:

[image]

Comment: That is what I've done!