# How to show accidentally hidden menu bar?

Tags: interface

Here is the blender window I have:

[image]

As you see, it doesn't have the menu that is usually displayed at the top of the screen.

How can I get the menu back?

Comment: To save some time in the future, spend some time reading this page of the manual on how to customize the interface: https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/areas.html

Comment: Also related: https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/screens.html# and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked

Answer (score 4):

You probably [**Maximized the active window**](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/window_system/areas.html#toggle-maximize-area).

To go back, try hovering your cursor over the Main 3D view, and type in the following key combination:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Even if the window is maximized the fact that you can see the trainagle in the corner, means that you can add the menu. [icYou](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/27873/icyou) has the correct answer but made this and maybe it helps...

[image]

Comment: The shortcut key has been changed as of 2.8 to ctrl-spacebar.

Answer (score 1):

You have maximized your 3d viewport by hitting ctrl-spacebar.  Others correctly answered above, but the shortcut keys have changed in 2.8

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and to solve it it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure what menu you are looking for but just change the dropdown for one of your screens to this icon.[image]

You may have to move screens around to get them back to the place you want.

[image]

Click the box of any of the green circles and choos the "i" icon.

Comment: I don't see such icon on my window. Do you?

Comment: Actually I think Rick Riggs is correct. You "maximized" your 3d viewport by hitting shift + spacebar. You need to do that again to go back to regular view. Whatever window your mouse cursor is in gets maximized and minimized by hitting shift+spacebar.