# Can the 'top' view be rotated by 180° around the Z-axis by default?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, customization

Is it somehow possible to have the top view (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>) rotated by 180 degrees by default?

I can get the view I'm after using the key combination <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> then `12 x` <kbd>Numpad 6</kbd> (or `12 x` <kbd>Numpad 4</kbd>).

I was hoping that there is some option or setting to rotate this default top-view orientation by 180° around the Z-axis?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to look at the x-y plane, such that +x is pointing left and +y is down?

Comment: @RonProctor, Yes. I would like to have hitting `Numpad 7` result in a top-down view, with positive x pointing left and positive y pointing down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to customize the default orientation as far I know (maybe some clever person could write a script and assign it to the numpad keys)

As an alternative you can change the default scene.

Rotate the view to where you need it, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to save the startup file. That way blender will always open with your preset view.

Make sure that the Load UI (load User Interface) box is enabled on the user preferences>file>load & save section.

You could also create custom layouts and save those as part of the startup file, that way instead of changing the views, change to the layout that has the orientation you want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>

See this related post: [Can screen layouts be locked?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post. But just wanted to add that now you can hold down alt and rotate around with the scroll wheel to snap to different angles.