# Faster way to rotate top view by 180 degrees

Tags: 3d-view

When working in top view I would prefer the view to be 180 degrees rotated along the Y axis like in the image. I can rotate the view when in top view by pressing numpad+6 a bunch of times, but it's a bit tedious to do every time. Is there a faster way than that to do what I want?

There's a related question [Can the 'top' view be rotated by 180° around the Z-axis by default?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79964/can-the-top-view-be-rotated-by-180-around-the-z-axis-by-default), which asks if the top view can be changed by default, which it evidently can't, by what I'm wondering is if there's at least a quicker way to get to that desired view?

[image]

Comment: Well, you can set up a camera in this orientation, and then just switch to it by pressing *Num 0*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> then <kbd>Numpad 9</kbd>.

After that <kbd>Numpad 9</kbd> will invert the view.

[image]

Globally: <kbd>Numpad 9</kbd> goes to the opposite view. But for top and bottom view using <kbd>Shift</kbd> set it to rotate 180 degrees.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!

Comment: So the sole difference between toggling top and bottom view with and without `Shift`, is that it in former case it allows you to rotate 180 degrees with Numpad 9, right?

Comment: Yes with shift rotate 180 or if not shift opposite view.