# I'm having trouble putting my windows views back, I tried a few things and they won't go back, they did before

Tags: 3d-view, interface

[image]So this is a little embarrassing. I have gotten really far on this Harbor Seal project and i can't figure out how to close my python code info viewer? the large arrow won't appear. I have recently saved, I like what I have. Any suggestions?
Is there python script that can hide my python viewer? or simply set to regular format?

Comment: If an area is not the same size as the next direction, it will not merge to another area.  You have a small puzzle to figure out.

Comment: Instead of re-arranging windows all the time and making a mess of the interface, you can make custom layouts that accommodate your workflow. Then use Ctrl and the left and right arrows to move across different layouts. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183

Answer (score 1):

The simple way (that doesn't involve careful dragging of a corner) is to right-click the line between two windows - eg, the horizontal between the two top-right frames - and select 'Join Area'. You can then left-click the panel that you want to close. Note, however, that as mentioned by @Timaroberts, you can only do this on frames that match in width/height - otherwise you have to join other areas until the panels you want to join match in size.