# How can I hide all the animation controls?

Tags: modeling, interface

I am only interested in modeling and not animation. Is there a way I can hide all the animation related panels from the blender interface? They take up screen real estate that I could use for other tools.

Comment: Read: [Can screen layouts be locked?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either change the view type
[image]

or just combine one view with another by right clicking the edge between them
[image]

Comment: Remember you can Switch to, Create New and Duplicate Screen layouts from the drop down at the top of the screen.