# How to return view window back to original location

Tags: interface

How can I return my view window back to the original location?

Specifically, I want to have options panel to the right of the view window.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Read:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [Workspaces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/workspaces.html) and use the Next button at the bottom to see more detail. Should answer your questions.