# I made a lot of windows with the vertical split option

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I made many vertical splits when I was trying to join them. To collapse them I joined the split over the original copy. Is there a way for me to get back to the original window?

Comment: Stop splitting windows and use layouts/workspaces See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-or-workspaces-be-locked/34183#34183

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1 (without closing your file)**
[image]

1. On the Workspace bar click on `+` to add a new workspace
2. Optional: delete the old one

**Option 2**

1. `Save File` and close Blender
2. Than open Blender again
3. Click top left on `File` > `Open`
4. In the pop-up screen click top right on the Gear Icon
5. Uncheck `Load UI` (user interface)
6. Select your File to Open

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to open the file through `File>Open` or `Ctrl+O` and disable `Load UI`:

[image: save as dialog]

Then it will use your default layout and you can save the file to make it permanent.