# The window to set the textures is missing

Tags: texturing

so I downloaded this gun online, and it has no textures. Usually their is a section on the right with many categories... one lets you add textures, but when I opened this blender file there was no option to add textures, here is a picture.[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus. Your layout is setup to show only 3D Viewport. The materials and textures tab along with many others is located in Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the properties window opened, where you will find the 'Textures' tab. If you look in the bottom right corner. There's a small cube with two arrows, next to the 'View' menu. Click that cube, and select 'Properties' to display that window.