# Blender initial interface

Tags: interface

I'm currently working on a project on Blender and I'm still trying to familiarise myself with the interface so I'm quite a beginner at the moment. I was working on a figure and then I'm not quite sure what I clicked on it took me to a different interface other than the initial one where you edit the figures and stuff.

This is what I'm getting when I open my saved project

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: "Figure" is not a common term, here, and in art jargon is refers specifically to a human form. What do you mean by "figure?" Do you mean a mesh (aka 3D Model)?

Comment: please read this post to familiarize with blender's interface: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8394/1853

Comment: @cegaton I will look into that thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably clicked the *Render* button at the top of the *Properties panel*. Anyway, it changed the *3D Viewport* to a *UV Image Editor*. To change it back, either key <kbd>Esc</kbd> once or twice or if that doesn't work, notice the bottom left-hand corner of the image editor. There is a little picture there that looks sort of like a sunset. Click on it, and select *3D View* instead.

*This picture from [here](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics) should help explain what I mean:*

[image]

*Just know that you would select 3D View instead.*

Comment: @Scarl Glad that you got what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Blender interface is entirely customizable. You can create as many panes as you want, arrange them however you want, and any pane can be for any context/view. This is great... once you know what's going on ;-)

The default layout is very similar to what you're showing, so I'm guessing that you're wanting the 3D Viewport (where you edit meshes) to be back in the largest pane, where it usually is. You can do this by choosing the "3D View" from the drop-down menu on the bottom left of that pane.

The way you got there is probably by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>, which brings up the render result (which is what you're looking at) without starting a new render. Rendering will also do this. Either pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or pressing the Render button automatically replaces one of your panes (I'm not quite sure how it chooses which one) with the Image Editor, which is also where you view the final rendered image. Typically, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will return the Image Editor view to whatever it was before. Sometimes that doesn't work, but you can always* manually choose the 3D View again.

*The one case you can't change the view is if a pane is maximized. Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>up</kbd> will toggle the pane your mouse cursor is in from its normal size to taking over the whole screen. This is a good way to maximize screen real estate when you're focused on a particular task, but it can be disconcerting if you don't know what's going on.

Incidentally, the 3D View is also what you have for the bottom right pane, which is usually the "Properties" view. If you change that back to the Properties view, it will be more-or-less back to the default layout.

Comment: Thank you for this, this helped me test a lot of different options and know how to go back to what I was working on!