# Is there a keyboard shortcut to open and close these areas?

Tags: interface, shortcut

I accidentally closed the panel that has a red circle (I dont know the name of it lol). I had to close everything and load the project again and untick the 'load UI' to restore that panel again. Is there a shortcut to open/close it similar to properties and toolbar panel?

[image: blender's UI]

I tried the answers from the duplicate but I'm talking about specifically the panel on the right side with the red circle on it. I'm just wondering if it has a shortcut button like the toolbar <kbd>T</kbd> and properties <kbd>N</kbd> panel.

Comment: Actually your highlighted area consists of 2 *Area* types (called *Outliner* and *Property Area*) rather than one *Panel*. Related questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34174/can-screen-layouts-be-locked/34183#34183

Comment: Very likely that you pressed `Shift+Spacebar` by accident and toggled the 3D view fullscreen.

Comment: FINALLY so its shift+spacebar.....THANK YOU SIR! :D

Comment: @Shaun, yes `Shift+Spacebar` will toggle full screen for any view area the mouse cursor is in.

Answer (score 3):

Just keep the cursor in the *3D View* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>.