# Why can't I see my layout view when in Shading mode?

Tags: 3d-view, shaders

I want to apply a texture to my object, but my window to view my object has disappeared when in shading mode. It has worked in the past, I'm not sure how to get the view back up.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus