3D viewport have dissapeared in Layout workspace
I have some problems with diferent sections/screens dissapearing while i am modeling in blender.
My 3D viewport is gone when I am in layout (it is there in for example the modeling bar.
How can I get it back? Se photos



https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus

It seems you have merged the Timeline area with the 3D Viewport area (i.e. closed the viewport window).
To get it back, open a new scene by opening Blender or if it already is open, press Ctrl+N > New > General. This should open the default screen with the Layout tab selected and only showing the Timeline.
Go into the top left corner of the Timeline window left to where you can switch the editor window until the cursor becomes a cross or plus symbol. Then press the left mouse button and drag down to split the area. Drag down until the upper window is large enough how you want it as 3D Viewport. Then click on the editor dropdown menu and switch the upper window to 3D Viewport or press Shift+F5.
Now go to the File menu and choose Defaults > Save Startup File and confirm with OK.
This way you can change the default Layout scene for each startup of Blender or when creating a new General scene. Opening a new scene before getting the viewport back is advisable to make sure you have no other settings changed from the defaults which you do not want to save in the startup file.
This is in case you have this problem at each startup. If it is only in this project, just drag down the new area without saving a startup file, just like described in the other answer.

one solution: Delete your Layout workspace, then add (+) it back.
one solution: in the corner of the timeline view (when your cursor shows a '+' symbol, drag to create another (duplicate timeline) view panel, and then change the Editor type into a 3D Viewport.

When she has changed the startup file, deleting the Layout workspace and adding it back will only get her the same Timeline window as it was before. And splitting the area to create a new 3D Viewport window without saving as startup file will only help until she creates a new project or opens Blender the next time.

@GordonBrinkmann -- she mentions nothing about permanent problem but about "dissapearing while i am modeling", so I took her question as aked.  So I didn't focus on Default::Startup file.  I guess I didn't think about all possibilities.

Yeah, you're right, she does not mention it. I guess I just experienced it too often here that users forgot to mention crucial information for answering their question, so I do more than needed  And since this site aims to be a kind of knowledge database that other users with similar problems can benefit from as well instead of just helping one individual user, I thought I should mention other possibilities.
